# upside-down program in /usr/bin/games

Tags: linux

Was I imagining it?  I'm sure many linux distros used to come with a program in /usr/bin/games that 'faked' upside down fixed width text.  So for example if you input

```
hello
```

it would output

```
o773y
```

or something along those lines.

But on the boxes I have logins on these days, it's not there, and I can't find any mention of it on google.  Can anyone point me towards a copy of the program please? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some searching I found it!

`apt-get install filters`

Cool stuff :D

```
13:37 me@luastoned:/usr/games > ./upside-down
hello
o77ay
```

Yep, this is fun.

```
13:48 me@luastoned:/usr/games > ./eleet
Am I leet enough for this?
4m 1 l33t 3n0ugh f0r th15?
```

Edit: Found the homepage:
http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/filters/

Comment: Excellent.  Now I can send text to my mate in Australia.